# How to match and batch entities to assemble in arena when same entities are required for different parts?

Tags: arena-simulation

I am simulating a manufacturing model where I have entities C1, C2......C5. All of these arrive at a station where they need to assembled to form a part.  Now Part A requires c1 and c3 entity  where as part B requires C3 C4 C5 entity. Now how do I differentiate them for the two parts as arena only does it based on entity type and attribute

I tried to assign component identifier as a attribute but since C3 is an entity required for both parts How do Ask arena to pick up C3 for both parts?

Answer (score 2):

Use a bitvector for your attribute

```
   76543210   <- bit number
C1 00000001b
C2 00000000b
C3 00000011b
C4 00000010b
C5 00000010b
         ^^
        /  \
        B   A
```

The entities that have their bit 0 set, assemble into part A.
The entities that have their bit 1 set, assemble into part B.